# automatically update html with json at certain times of day

Tags: jquery, html, json, real-time-updates

I'm helping a community radio station build a new web site. We'd like to have a `div` that displays the title and host of the current program.

My idea is to turn the radio schedule into a json file that feeds the html page.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to feed only the relevant show info to html based on the time of day?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, then what libraries help accomplish this? For example, can jQuery.getJSON parse json based on time? (I haven't seen any info about this in their docs.) Are there other libraries that would be better suited for this task?

Comment: Return the show start/end times in your JSON. Then compare those to the current time to find the show which is currently on air. `jQuery.getJSON` would only be used to retrieve the data. You can use the callback to perform your required logic on it.

Comment: This all depends on the json file set up and the controls you use to implement it. For instance, you could have an `$.ajax` call to get the json file, then, in the `success` callback, if you're data is return as a json object, you need only compare show start/end to current `new Date()` in js. In other words, something like `for (x in data) { var show = data[x]; if (show.timeStart > date && show.timeEnd < date) { do work } }`

Comment: Something else to keep in mind, if you use `$.ajax` with the setting `type="json"` AND have the server return a json string [in PHP `return json_encode(data);`] then the data will be an object in the success call

Comment: also, take note of estshy's answer and dealing with timezones. Best to use a UTC comparison for sake of timezones. However, all those comments aside, I would make sure the serving server had the correct time for the radio station and would simply do all the work to get what to display serverside, then only send that to the client

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan By "use the callback to perform your required logic", are you referring to the `[success]` part of `jQuery.getJSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, updated

Try

v2

```
(function () {
    // `titles`, i.e.g., `"morning program"`, `"afternoon program"` , etc.
    var titles = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"
                  , "5", "6", "7", "8"
                  , "9", "10", "11", "12"
                  , "13", "14", "15", "16"
                  , "17", "18", "19", "20"
                  , "21", "22", "23", "24"];
    var schedule = (function () {
        var _schedule = $.map(new Array(24), function (k, v) {
            return ["hour " + "<em>" 
                    + v + "</em> " 
                    + new Date().toLocaleString() 
                    + " <em>program " 
                    + titles[new Date().getHours()] 
                    + "</em>"]
        });
        return $("div")
        .html(_schedule[new Date().getHours()]) 
        && $("em").css("color", "blue");
    }());
    schedule();
    var s = setInterval(function () {
        schedule();
    }, 10000);
}());

// v1

// A rough draft pattern . 

// Edit, logic could probably use some adjustments , 
// i.e.g., when moving from `9:00:00 AM` to `10:00:00 AM`
// would necessitate adjusting from `.slice(-10)` to `slice(-11)` ; 
// minimization of redundancies, testing of logic with all possible schedules , 
// date values within ternary 

//    var schedule = {
//        "9:00:00 AM": "Morning Show",
//        "10:00:00 AM": "Afternoon Show"
//    };

//    var t = "9:00:00 AM";
//    var y = new Date().toLocaleString().slice(-11).replace(/:/g, "");
//    y.indexOf("AM") != -1 
//    ? (Number(y.replace(/\s+\w+/g, "")) > Number(t.replace(/:|[a-z]/gi, "")) && Number(y.replace(/\s+\w+/g, "")) < 100000 
//      ? (schedule.hasOwnProperty("9:00:00 AM") 
//        ? $("div").html(schedule["9:00:00 AM"]) // optional jquery `.load()` , `$.post()`
//        : $("div").html("next scheduled programming...")) // optional jquery `.load()` , `$.post()`
//      : $("div").html("next scheduled programming...")) // notification , error message
//    : $("div").html("next scheduled programming..." + schedule["10:00:00 AM"]); // notification , error message
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/YV83k/

Answer (score 2):

You can get current time from user and then filter your array from json to get relevant information. Remember always to get UTC time, because users can have different timezones. I recommend you using [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to accomplish that in this way.

If you don't have all the data at one time you can still fetch data from server every x seconds. There will be helpful function [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

Comment: agreed, most definitely on the issue of UTC